# Python: Most efficient way to compare two lists of integers

Tags: python, performance, list, comparison

I'm trying to compare two lists of integers, each the same size, in Python 2.6. The comparison I need is to compare the first item in List 1 with the first item in List 2, the second item in List 1 with the second item in List 2, and so on, and returns a result if ALL of the list items follow the same comparison criteria. It should behave as follows:

```
list1 = [1,1,1,1]
list2 = [2,1,2,3]
compare(list1,list2) 
# returns a "list 1 is <= list 2" response.

list1 = [4,1,4,3]
list2 = [2,1,2,3]
compare(list1,list2) 
# returns a "list 1 is >= list 2" response.

list1 = [3,2,3,2]
list2 = [1,4,1,4]
compare(list1,list2) 
# returns None— some items in list1 > list2, and some items in list2 > list1.
```

I figured I could write the code like the following block, but I don't know if it's the most efficient. My program is going to be calling this method a LOT so I want to streamline this as much as possible.

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    gt_found = 0
    lt_found = 0
    for x in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[x] > list2[x]:
            gt_found += 1
        elif list1[x] < list2[x]:        
            lt_found += 1
        if gt_found > 0 and lt_found > 0:
            return None   #(some items >, some items <)
    if gt_found > 0:
        return 1          #(list1 >= list2)
    if lt_found > 0:
        return -1         #(list1 <= list2)
    return 0              #(list1 == list2)
```

Is it already as good as it's going to get (big-O of n), or is there a faster way to go about it (or a way that uses system functions instead)?

CLARIFICATION: I expect the case that returns 'None' to happen the most often, so it is important.

Comment: What if you sort both lists and then compare them, if element in  first one that isn't the same in the second one then end the function. Worst case would be n.

Comment: I think that might make it worse case in general, because if there's an item that is > and another item that is <, they'll get blown to opposite ends of the sorted list.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: That won't give the same results as the OP's desired algorithm.  Consider trying to compare `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2,1]` that way.

Comment: @jwodder Ah, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider a numpy-based vectorized comparison.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,1,1,2]
b = [2,2,4,3]

all_larger = np.all(np.asarray(b) > np.asarray(a))  # true if b > a holds elementwise

print all_larger

        True
```

Clearly, you can engineer the thing to have your answer.

```
all_larger = lambda b,a : np.all(np.asarray(b) > np.asarray(a))

if all_larger(b,a):
       print "b > a"
elif all_larger(a,b):
       print "a > b"

else
       print "nothing!"
```

Every type of comparison such as `<, >, <=, >=,` can be done.

Comment: Ooh, hadn't thought of that. Does it do >= and <=?

Comment: @SoItBegins, sure it does.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll compare the two answers I got and see which is fastest.

Comment: @SoItBegins Tell us what you come up with. I'm betting this one might be faster than mine, numpy being a numerics library that excels at things like matrix math. Would never have thought of this, personally. Kudos to Acorbe.

Comment: @SoItBegins, numpy is designed for doing things like this. In principle you'd go even faster if you work natively with numpy arrays which store information contiguously in memory (hence no random memory access is required during the comparison operation.)

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with the wonderful `zip` function?

```
import itertools

def compare(xs, ys):
  all_less = True
  all_greater = True

  for x, y in itertools.izip(xs, ys):
    if not all_less and not all_greater:
      return None
    if x > y:
      all_less = False
    elif x < y:
      all_greater = False

  if all_less:
    return "list 1 is <= list 2"
  elif all_greater:
    return "list 1 is >= list 2"
  return None  # all_greater might be set False on final iteration
```

Zip takes two lists (`xs` and `ys` in this case, but call them whatever you want) and creates an iterator for a sequence of tuples.

```
izip([1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1]) == [(1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1)]
```

This way you can iterate through both lists simultaneously and compare each value in tandem. The time complexity should be O(n), where n is the size of your lists.

It will return early in cases where neither the >= or <= condition are met.

#### Update

As **James Matta** points out, `itertools.izip` performs better than the standard `zip` in Python 2. This isn't true in Python 3, where the standard `zip` works the way `izip` does in older versions.

Comment: No need for those parentheses with `if` and Python is spaced with four spaces (PEP8).

Comment: @SoItBegins There were some bugs in the code. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @NeilG Yeah, I'm totally not a python programmer (if that's not horribly obvious). Extraneous parens removed.

Comment: No worries.  Fixed a small bug in your code and renamed variables to lowercase with underscores as indicated by PEP8.

Comment: @NeilG Thanks. I think I'm stuck in Scala/Haskell mode mentally, on the naming side of things.

Comment: You need to be careful with the built in zip, it can be bad if the lists are too long. If you have long lists its is better to use the itertools izip( ... ).

Comment: @JamesMatta Is that still true in Python 3? I notice that "zip" returns a `zip object`, rather than a list of tuples. I also notice that the docs for itertools in Python 3 don't mention an `izip` function.

Comment: @KChaloux To be perfectly honest I don't know. You are probably right though. I still use python 2.7.5, as it is currently too much of a chore to port all the Python scripts I use for data analysis at this point in my PhD studies.

Comment: @JamesMatta, @KChaloux: Looking at the code, `zip` in Python 3.2 is almost identical to `itertools.izip` in Python 2.7.

Comment: @AlexBrault Cool beans. I thought I heard about them doing things like that in 3. I believe `range` got a similar treatment.

Comment: @KChaloux: In my defense, a quick re-reading of the question has him specifying python 2.6

Comment: @James Ah, I actually missed that entirely. I'll edit the answer to use itertools then, and mention that `zip` in Python 3.2 works as `izip` in Python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the performance of the two methods, I named the iterative method 'tortoise' and the numpy method 'hare', and tested it with the code below.

At first, the 'tortoise' won [.009s [T] vs .033s [H]], but I checked it and found that asarray() was being called more often than it need to be. With that fix, the 'hare' won again, [.009s [T] vs .006s [H]].

The data is here: http://tny.cz/64d6e5dc 
It consists of 28 lines of about 950 elements in length. Four of the lines collectively >= all the others.

It might be interesting to see how the performance works on larger data sets.

```
import itertools, operator, math
import cProfile
import numpy as np

data = #SEE PASTEBIN

def tortoise(xs, ys):
    all_less = True
    all_greater = True

    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        if not all_less and not all_greater:
          return None
        if x > y:
          all_less = False
        elif x < y:
          all_greater = False

    if all_greater and all_less:
        return 0
    if all_greater:
        return 1
    if all_less:
        return -1
    return None  # all_greater might be set False on final iteration


hare = lambda b,a : np.all(b >= a)

def find_uniques_tortoise():
    include_list = range(len(data))
    current_list_index = 0
    while current_list_index < len(data):
        if current_list_index not in include_list:
            current_list_index += 1
            continue
        for x in range(current_list_index+1,len(data)):
            if x not in include_list:
                continue
            result = tortoise(data[current_list_index], data[x])
            if result is None: #no comparison
                continue 
        elif result == 1 or result == 0: # this one beats the other one
            include_list.remove(x)
            continue
        elif result == -1: #the other one beats this one
            include_list.remove(current_list_index)
            break
    current_list_index +=1
return include_list

def find_uniques_hare():
    include_list = range(len(data))
    current_list_index = 0
    #do all asarray()s beforehand for max efficiency
    for x in range(len(data)): 
        data[x] = np.asarray(data[x])
    while current_list_index < len(data):
        if current_list_index not in include_list:
            current_list_index += 1
            continue
        for x in range(current_list_index+1,len(data)):
            if x not in include_list:
                continue
            if hare(data[current_list_index], data[x]): # this one beats the other one, or it's a tie
                include_list.remove(x)
            #   print x
                continue
            elif hare(data[x], data[current_list_index]): #the other one beats this one
                include_list.remove(current_list_index)
            #   print current_list_index
                break
            else: #no comparison
                continue
        current_list_index +=1
    return include_list             



cProfile.run('find_uniques_tortoise()')
cProfile.run('find_uniques_hare()')

print find_uniques_tortoise()
print   
print find_uniques_hare()
```